# Running database migrations in Cloud Build with Cloud SQL Proxy

Tags: postgresql, docker, google-cloud-platform, prisma, google-cloud-build

I have a Dockerfile in which I've defined database migration process:

```
...
ARG DATABASE_URL
ENV DATABASE_URL
RUN npx prisma migrate deploy --schema ./prisma/schema.prisma
...
```

This is my Cloud Build trigger yaml:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - '-c'
      - >-
        docker build --build-arg
        DATABASE_URL=$$DATABASE_URL --no-cache -t
        $_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA . -f
        Dockerfile
    id: Build
    entrypoint: bash
    secretEnv:
      - DATABASE_URL
  # Rest of the steps
images:
  - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
  dynamicSubstitutions: true
substitutions:
  # My substitions
tags:
  # My tags
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/my-project-id/secrets/DATABASE_URL/versions/1
      env: DATABASE_URL
```

My `DATABASE_URL` is set to something like `postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@my.ip.is.here:5432/postgres`

This does not currently work, since (I guess) I'm not able to whitelist the IP that's trying to connect to this database instance (and I want to keep it this way).

The only workaround I found would be to connect using database's `Connection Name` (e.g. `project-123456:us-central1:my-database`).

I've been trying to accomplish this with Cloud SQL Proxy, following the [guides like this one](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-build), yet without any success.

I've also tried adding the following as the first step, and changing the `DATABASE_URL` to `postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@127.0.01:5432/postgres`, yet then it runs indefinitely, not allowing other steps to even start:

```yaml
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy'
  id: Proxy
  args:
    - 'project-123456:us-central1:my-database'
```

What would be the correct way of making sure my prisma command, that depends on the `DATABASE_URL` can connect to the instance and apply the migrations?

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: Can you try to add `--network cloudbuild` to your build command line?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Just to clarify – should I use the `DATABASE_URL` secret like `postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@127.0.01:5432/postgres` then, assuming it will try to connect via Cloud SQL Proxy?

Comment: Yes but a container is an isolated environment!